# java SimpleDateFormat get wrong date from a negative timeStamp of Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just want order my registers in a descending order. I'm using the method `orderByChild()` from `DatabaseReference`:

```
private void listPersons() {

        databaseReference.child("Persons").orderByChild("timeStamp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listPersonas.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot objSnaptshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Persona p = objSnaptshot.getValue(Person.class);
                    listPersons.add(p);
                }
    ....
        });
    }
```

Here are my persons without a negative timestamp:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7lp.jpg
Persons in firebase database:

```
2019/05/31 03:13:22 timestamp: ->1559333602000
2020/09/10 02:50:52 timestamp: ->1599767452000
2020/10/31 02:15:34 timestamp: ->1604171734423
```

There is not problems before to add the negative symbol, but when I put the negative symbol to use `orderByChild()` the date from this method is wrong:

```
public String timeStampToDate(Object timestamp){

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss").format(timestamp);

    return date;
}
```

I got:

```
2019/05/31 03:13:22 timestamp: -> -1559333602000
2020/09/10 02:50:52 timestamp: -> -1599767452000
2020/10/31 02:15:34 timestamp: -> -1604171734423

1919/03/02 11:44:25
1919/04/22 11:09:08
1920/08/02 10:46:38
```

I don't know why my dates are wrong I just put the negative symbol with the goal of get my registers in descending order. The method `public String timeStampToDate` is inside of my model class `Person` I'm using this method inside my `listview adapter`:

```
regdate.setText(personModel.timeStampToDate(personModel.getTimeStamp()));
```

Of this way I'm registering my persons:

```
 Person p = new Person();
                p.setIdperson(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                p.setName(name);
                p.setPhone(phone);
                p.setTimeStamp(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                databaseReference.child("Persons").child(p.getIdperson()).setValue(p);
```

As we can see I'm using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to get a firebase timestamp. Now I should register my timestamp multiplying by -1. well. I hope that i was clear with my problem.
thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: 31/10/2020 MY SOLUTION TO SHOW THE NORMAL DATE:**

my solution to show a normal date and not wrong was `multiply` the `timestamp` by `-1` of this way I get the normal timestamp and therefore a normal date:

```
  public String timeStampToDate(Object timestamp){
        long value = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(timestamp));
        long normaldate = value * -1;
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss").format(normaldate);
        return date;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to send to firebase database a `negative timestamp`. I was reading that I should use a "cloud function" that convert the timestamp automatically to negative, but I don't know how do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I went through your question three times but I could not get your question.

Comment: I fixed my problem basically when I send a negative timestamp to `SimpleDateFormat` it get a wrong date. Now i want to send a `negative timestamp` to the firebase database to keep my timestamps of every person in negative. I don't know how do that. Please help me sir. I did it: `"-"+ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but I got this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-{.sv=timestamp}"`. thanks sir.

Comment: Some one told me that is not good get the +ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in the cliente instead id. I fixed my problem getting the current date from java calendar in miliseconds and then I multiply by -1 and then I send it to the server.